# Looking for sound files from a VERY old version of Chessmaster Live

Tags: online-chess, chessmaster

I've been searching (for a long time) for some sound files to a chess program from way, way back (early 90's).  There was an online version of Chessmaster called Chessmaster Live.  I'm sure it is a long shot, but does anyone have a copy of this program or know where I might find it so that I can get the sound files?

The sound files are basically the sounds that are made as one moved a piece, captured, castled etc.

Answer (score 2):

Let me suggest another way.

You are assuming that the game had sounds in the form of files that are reusable. This may not be the case.
But why not start searching for files yourself with search terms like [mp3 chess pieces](https://www.google.nl/search?q=mp3+chess+pieces) (or [chess pieces sounds](https://www.google.nl/search?q=chess+pieces+sounds) or [sound effects chess moves](https://www.google.nl/search?q=sound+effects+chess+moves), or other variations)? These will lead to e.g.:

- [Soundsnap board game sounds](http://www.soundsnap.com/taxonomy/term/12103/alpha) (not free)
- [Sound Hills Chess Pieces and Board sounds](http://audiojungle.net/item/chess-pieces-and-board/11657386) (not free)
- [Pond5 Chess piece sound effects](http://www.pond5.com/sound-effects/1/chess-piece.html#1/2080/chess,piece) (not free)

The rest is left *as an exercise to the reader* ;-)

I found that chess.com actually has [a question about this](https://www.chess.com/forum/view/general/sound-fx-for-moves) as well.

Any of these may good enough for you.

Answer (score 2):

On this forum: http://www.chessbanter.com/rec-games-chess-computer-computer/17342-chessmaster-online-sound-effects.html, one member says the same sound effects were used throughout the desktop applications (up through CM9000).

Is it possible a version of Chessmaster--like 6000--would contain those sound effects.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it might be Chessmaster 5500 according to this article -http://www.gamespot.com/reviews/chessmaster-6000-review/1900-2538403/
. This might be available to buy online or as abandonware, though no guarantees about the legality of this.

Comment: Actually, it's not.  This was specifically the online version called "Chessmaster Live!"  Thanks anyway.